# How do I specialise with an explicit type application?

Tags: haskell

With GHC 8.0, I can write an ambiguous function that's overloaded over some type not mentioned in the main part of its type signature, and then call it using an explicit type application:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes,
             AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, TypeFamilies #-}

showRead :: forall t . (Read t, Show t) => String -> String
showRead x = show (read x :: t)

showReadInt = showRead @Int
```

I'd like to use a [`SPECIALIZE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma) pragma to force a specialisation of `showRead` for `Int` (my real code has the actual call site in a different module). However, the normal `SPECIALIZE` syntax is based on writing the main part of the type signature, e.g.:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE showRead :: String -> String #-}
```

and in this case that doesn't allow me to specify what `t` should be, and predictably gives an error about it being ambiguous.

I tried using an equality constraint:

```
{-# SPECIALISE showRead :: forall t . (Read t, Show t, t ~ Int) => String -> String #-}
```

but that just gave the error:

> ```
> • Could not deduce (Read t0) a SPECIALISE pragma for ‘showRead’
>   from the context: (Read t, Show t, t ~ Int)
>     bound by the type signature for:
>                showRead :: (Read t, Show t, t ~ Int) => String -> String
>     at foo.hs:4:1-76
>   The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
> ```

Is there any way I can do this? Of course I could just use a `Proxy`, but it seems a shame not to use the shiny new way instead.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that the ability to use ambiguous functions like this is very new, thanks to GHC8's new type application syntax. So I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is "it's not supported yet"

Comment: In this context, you're specializing to an *argument* more than a *signature*. I don't know that the type specialization process makes much sense here. One option might be to use a proxy behind the scenes to get specialization while presenting this weird new interface to the world (I'm not entirely sold on it yet).

Comment: @dfeuer: I think it's just that the existing /syntax/ isn't well-suited for specifying it. The only real difference between the proxy and the ambiguous type is whether the type parameter is explicit or implicit.

Comment: I don't see the difference between adding specialization for explicit type arguments and adding specializations for value arguments. Maybe general argument specialization is the way to go?

Comment: Sounds plausible, but might be significantly more work than just exposing the existing type specialization functionality for ambiguous types. If there's a good syntax that can express both, perhaps that could be used but the value specialisation left unimplemented initially.

Comment: I'd try to code this using the `RULES` pragma, but I don't expect it to work, currently.

Comment: @chi: with `RULES` couldn't I wind up inadvertently rewriting to the wrong specialization? If I can't specify an appropriate constraint on `t` on the left-hand side of the rule, it might apply too often.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam True. I was wondering about something like `RULES showRead @Int = showReadInt`

Comment: Maybe just slap an INLINE on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported in GHC 8.0, but is now the subject of a [proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/15/files) to support it in future GHCs.